# Understanding extracting data from server-side rendering websites

Tags: web-scraping, backend

I am actually very new to backend web development, and I am reading this blog about web scraping. It quotes

> The target web page does not rely on JavaScript to retrieve data or for rendering purposes. Thus, you do not need a tool that is able to run JavaScript in the browser. In other word, you do not have to use a headless browser library to extract data from the target web page. You can use such a library, but it is not necessary.

For background context, I am trying to choose which web scraping libraries I should use.
My question is:

Shouldn't it be impossible to extract data using a browser library since the data is from a server-side rendered?

It may be a stupid question, but forgive me as I said I am new to backend. Here's the link to the blog for reference [Web Scraping With node.js](https://brightdata.com/blog/how-tos/web-scraping-with-node-js#:%7E:text=As%20shown%20here%2C%20you%20can,the%20scraped%20data%20to%20JSON.)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be impossible to extract data using a browser library since the data is from a server-side rendered?

No, that makes it easier.

With a server rendered HTML document you can make an HTTP request to the URL of the HTML document, then parse the resulting HTML, then extract the data from it.

If it was client-rendered then you would need to either:

- Make an HTTP request to the URL for the HTML document, then render it locally using a tool that will run all the JavaScript in it, wait for all the JavaScript to finish updating the DOM, then extract the data from it **or**
- Reverse engineer the client-side code to determine how it works, then duplicate that logic in your scraper so it can extract the data using the same logic that the website's client-side JS does.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract data from HTML which is contained in the response your browser receives from the server. You can then use some parsing library (for example, BeautifulSoup) to parse the HTML and get the data you need.